# Compilation of x264 project

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, msys

I had downloaded the [source of x264 library](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html).

The version of x264 is 148.

For compilation of shared dlls I am using the following command under
MSYS Environment:

```
./configure --disable-cli --enable-shared --prefix=.
```

The result is following:

```
platform:      X86_64
byte order:    little-endian
system:        WINDOWS
cli:           no
libx264:       internal
shared:        yes
static:        no
asm:           yes
interlaced:    yes
avs:           no
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        win32
opencl:        yes
filters:       crop select_every
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no
PIC:           yes
bit depth:     8
chroma format: all
```

After execution of make I have the following error:

```
common/win32thread.o:win32thread.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `_beginthreadex'
common/win32thread.o:win32thread.c:(.text+0x60): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_beginthreadex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:192: recipe for target 'libx264-148.dll' failed
make: *** [libx264-148.dll] Error 1
```

My working Environment:

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. MSYS64 with mingw64
3. Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

The configure command was executed without errors, but the make gives me the error described above.

Comment: Weird. *process.h* is part of [WinGW](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/36346635/). You might try `make -D__MSVCRT__`.

Comment: Dear Mr. Tim, Thank you very much for your answer. The goal is to build DLL in GCC environment. The option make -D__MSVCRT__ is related to MSVC environment. Command  $ make -D__MSVCRT__ give the error
make: invalid option -- D
make: invalid option -- _
make: invalid option -- _
make: invalid option -- M
make: invalid option -- V
Usage: make [options] [target] ...

Answer (score 3):

GCC is built by MSYS2/MinGW with different configurations, and bundled with different versions of MinGW-w64 headers/libs.

- MSYS2 only provides the posix thread model (pthreads); dwarf for i686, seh for x86_64.
- MinGW provides posix and win32 thread models; sjlj and dwarf for i686, seh and sjlj for x86_64.

Ergo, MSYS applications need to be built using the `pthreads` library. You can force an MSYS build of x264 to use the posix thread model, instead of the win32 model like this:

```
$ ./configure --disable-cli --enable-shared --disable-win32thread
```

> platform:      X86_64
>   byte order:    little-endian
>   system:        WINDOWS
>   cli:           yes
>   libx264:       internal
>   shared:        yes
>   static:        no
>   asm:           yes
>   interlaced:    yes
>   avs:           avisynth
>   lavf:          no
>   ffms:          no
>   mp4:           no
>   gpl:           yes
>   thread:        posix
>   opencl:        no
>   filters:       crop select_every
>   lto:           no
>   debug:         no
>   gprof:         no
>   strip:         no
>   PIC:           yes
>   bit depth:     all
>   chroma format: all
>
> You can run 'make' or 'make fprofiled' now.

The problem is, there is no `msys/winpthreads` package, so you would first need to cross-compile `pthreads-win32` for MSYS2.

---

Having said all that, you say

> For compilation of shared dlls

and not

> For compilation of .so shared libraries

So this seems like an x-Y problem to me. I think you should be using MSYS to cross-compile x264 like this:

```
$ ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-cli --enable-shared --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32-
```

(I would also use `--prefix=/usr/local`, as well as `--disable-opencl` for compatability with FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-thread
```

I had the same problem. It works with disabled thread.

Comment: It treats the symptom, but not the problem; now x264 will be limited to a single thread!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following option:

```
./configure --disable-cli --enable-shared
```

But didn't wanted to disable threads, so, what I did is modified `win32thread.c` like this:

Before:

```
  #if HAVE_WINRT
  /* _beginthreadex() is technically the correct option, but it's only available for Desktop applications.
   * Using CreateThread() as an alternative works on Windows Store and Windows Phone 8.1+ as long as we're
   * using a dynamically linked MSVCRT which happens to be a requirement for WinRT applications anyway */
  #define _beginthreadex CreateThread
  #define InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(a, b) InitializeCriticalSectionEx(a, b, CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO)
  #define WaitForSingleObject(a, b) WaitForSingleObjectEx(a, b, FALSE)
  #else
  #include <process.h>
  #endif
```

After

```
  #define _beginthreadex CreateThread

  #if HAVE_WINRT
  #define InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(a, b) InitializeCriticalSectionEx(a, b, CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO)
  #define WaitForSingleObject(a, b) WaitForSingleObjectEx(a, b, FALSE)
  #endif
```

Basically, I replaced `_beginthreadex` by Windows' native `CreateThread`. Not sure it's a huge problem for x264, but now I can compile.